# Open pdf in WebApp with manifest appcache

Tags: jquery, ipad, web-applications

I built a web app for offline use for the iPad. Everthing is working fine in the browser. i Can open the pdfs offline in a new window. But when i open the "fullscreen" web app and try to open a pdf it opens in the safari browser and there is nothing saved in the app cache -> 404 not found. How can i open a pdf in a web app from the manifest app cache either without switching to mobile safari or with?

Using jQuery Mobile.

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? Did you try displaying your pdf using object or embed (IE within a webpage rather than directly in the browser)?

Comment: unfortunately not...sorry